# Are questions about surveillance of Tor users on-topic?

Tags: discussion

Is the site mostly about the Tor technology, or does it also tackle social issues and challenges such as the possibility of e.g. NSA having exit nodes on Tor that analyze traffic and attempt to spot illegal activity, dissidents, etc?

Obviously, questions like `Is the NSA spying on Tor users?` are too broad and can't be definitively answered (and even if so, the question provokes "Yes!" and "No!" answers), but there are more focused questions which are possible in this arena, I think. Such as:

- How can I protect myself from malicious exit nodes?
- Is Tor still anonymous if accessed over unencrypted HTTP?

Comment: Seems completely reasonable to me just so long as they're not overly broad (as you said).

Comment: btw, I think that question has indeed been definitively answered.  But it requires full coverage of endpoints.  Also, keep in mind that this was developed specifically to prevent more-casual spies from exposing dissidents.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I don't see any problem with allowing questions around Tor surveillance. Questions about the effects or plausibility of traffic analysis are certainly on topic, as the answers should be fairly specific to Tor (due to its design decisions and compromises)