# Is this question about Tor's safety too broad?

Tags: discussion, vote-to-close

[This question](//tor.stackexchange.com/q/7418/71) asks "Is tor still as safe as it was before the takedown of Silk Road?" and seems fairly open-ended to me. I think any answers would be relatively speculative.

Whilst the question is a good conversation-starter, does the community feel it should be left open or closed as Too Broad?

<sub>See also: [Are questions about surveillance of Tor users on-topic?](https://tor.meta.stackexchange.com/q/3/71)</sub>

Comment: I had mixed feelings about it, but it also made me think that many people wonder about the same thing, so I felt it was best to answer it and keep it open.

I feel its better to answer them, to clear up misinformation and such.

Answer (score 1):

As far as I see it, this question is highly speculative and likely to attract discussions.

The OP states:

> After the government infiltrated (presumably an exit node) of the Tor network,

and presents this as a fact. However as far as I know there is no public knowledge that this really is or was the case. There were some occassions in the past where NSA/GCHQ ran middle nodes or where some LEA had and used a Firefox exploit, but I'm not aware of any case where a government "infiltrated the Tor network".

Furthermore the author asks

> is it still as safe for users who want their anonymity hidden …

Here we'd have to ask what the person means with "anonymity". Of course it is likely that some kind of anonymity can be degraded or the user can be deanonymized, but this depends on lots of factors. So the question also is too broad in my opinion.

I would definitely close this question.

Answer (score 1):

I agree with @Jens Kubieziel in that the OP presents unconfirmed information as a fact.

That is exactly what why I think this should not be closed. If there are no public knowledge on such Tor infiltrations and people are taking them as a fact, the Tor community has the responsibility to say "Hey look, there's no proof that Tor has been compromised". If they are misinformed, we should give them what is actually known and what is actually not known (and is probably a blow-up). That is what the answerer did.

I would definitely not close the question!

Answer (score 0):

The Tor security itself has not changed, there's always a risk of bad exit node or rendevouz point. I've made a simple patch, and I will continue my work in that direction soon(I hope). [Here it is](https://github.com/netsafe/tor-patches/blob/master/tor-route-length.patch). The question itself is broad, yes, but using this patch at least on Hidden Service node will make some good increase in difficulty to spot up the service. Also - I'll recommend NOT to use any unecrypted traffic, such as HTTP. Use HTTPS in conjunction with decentralized certificate mechanism, I'm using [Perspectives Project](http://perspectives-project.org/)